# Getting distinct not null dates from datetime collection

Tags: c#, .net, linq, collections, lambda

I have a collection of datetimes like this :

```
IEnumerable<DateTime?> dates
```

I'd like to get the collection of distinct **dates** sorting by descending

```
   IEnumerable<DateTime> dtCollection = dates.Where(x => x.HasValue).Distinct().OrderByDescending(x => x).AsEnumerable();
```

in the code above I get an exception of invalid cast,  and the distinct return the distinct (date+time) not the distinct dates .

So :

1. Why `Where(x => x.HasValue)` didn't discard all null values
2. How can I fix my codes to accomplish the task?

Thanks,

Comment: @GrantWinney    I want to ignore time I need just distinct date

Comment: For your `1`, because no one answered it : just because you do `HasValue`, you aren't actually converting your `DateTime?` to a `DateTime`.  It just grabs all items that are not null.  So then you need to grab the `Value` from those items, as seen in these answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use .Date to get the date component of a DateTime so:

```
dates
    .Where(x => x.HasValue)
    .Select(x => x.Value.Date)
    .Distinct()
    .OrderByDescending(x => x)
```

And in answer to your first point, `Where(x => x.HasValue)` *is* discarding all the nulls as you'd expect, but you're still left with a collection of `DateTime?` rather than `DateTime`, leading to type conversion error when you try to assign it to your `IEnumerable<DateTime> dtCollection`, so you need to use `x.Value` to convert each `DateTime?` to a `DateTime`.

Answer (score 1):

In the query, transform the `DateTime?` objects to `DateTime` by selecting their values:

```
IEnumerable<DateTime> dtCollection = dates
    .Where(x => x.HasValue)
    .Select(x => x.Value)
    .Distinct()
    .OrderByDescending(x => x)
    .AsEnumerable();
```

Since the `Where()` clause filters to only those which have a value, the `Select()` clause should succeed without error.  The output of that `Select()` is then a collection of `DateTime` instead of `DateTime?`.

Conversely, to only select one *property* of the `DateTime`, update that clause:

```
.Select(x => x.Value.Date)
```